# Black borders Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, compiz, bumblebee

After installing wine, I see the black borders everywhere and can't see my terminal:

[image]

I've reinstalled the wine, nvidia drivers and Bumblebee, but the problem still exist. Can anyone help me? The problem exist on every user of my ubuntu. Sorry for my English!

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if the above problem was solved, but, i came across the same problem on my laptop using ubuntu 14.04, and it was fixed when i update the system. on the top right of my screen there is a button, i pressed it, a menu appeared, i chose "about this computer", a screen open, i saw "install updates" on the bottom right, once i clicked it, the system showed me several updates, including updates for my graphic cards, i agreed for the updating and shut down my laptop. once turn on the laptop again, everything was set normally. 
this problem came to my laptop because of the blind upgrade that i did it through terminal "sudo apt-get upgrade" using the "xorg-edgers ppa". i don't know if we should use the mentioned ppa or not, but it is dangerous to upgrade the system blindly. sometimes, the latest updates are beta version and not stable. we need to be careful of that. thank you